# What is the difference between artisan queue:work and artisan horizon:work?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, laravel-5, laravel-horizon

I am using Laravel queues and Redis with Horizon. 
Supervisor is running `artisan horizon` which in turn spawns processes `/usr/bin/php7.2 artisan horizon:work redis`

Is there need to run `queue:work` at all or can Horizon already process the queue on its own?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With Horizon installed, the Artisan `queue:work` and `horizon:work` commands perform the same tasks, except that `horizon:work` accepts arguments that it uses to coordinate with a Horizon supervisor.

When running the Horizon supervisor process (via `artisan horizon`), we never need to execute `horizon:work` manually. The `horizon:work` command starts a queue worker process, and the supervisor runs it automatically when setting up worker pools.

By *supervisor*, I mean the Horizon manager process, not the system's *supervisord* which we use to start Horizon as a service.

In fact, `horizon:work` is marked *hidden*, so we won't even see it in the available commands shown by `artisan list`.

We can still execute `artisan queue:work` manually to run a single, standalone queue worker that isn't managed by Horizon.

The `artisan queue:work --once <connection>` command is more useful—this processes the next pending item in a queue and can help to debug misbehaving jobs in development.

For this to be effective, we need to run it after stopping any long-running queue workers so we can control when the job executes. Horizon makes this easy:

```
php artisan horizon:terminate
```

Answer (score 1):

Cy Rossignol's answer is right. But I will add more.

From [the official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/horizon#installation) says:

> Laravel Horizon requires that you use Redis to power your queue.
> Therefore, you should ensure that your queue connection is set to
> redis in your application's config/queue.php configuration file.

So the horizon is an enhancement of Laravel worker with dashboard and other features, but it  will only work for Redis. Not like default Laravel queue worker that support file,database, and other drivers that are supported by Laravel.

The benefit of using horizon:

- has a metrics dashboard which provides information regarding your job and queue wait times and throughput
- has ability to send webhook or Slack or SMS notifications
- has ability to pause and resume
- has ability to see and retry failed job in dashboard
- has worker balancing strategies (simple, auto, and false)
- has more custom configurations like maxProcesses, balanceMaxShift, balanceCooldown, etc