# Does the Laravel Horizon replace the standard Laravel queues?

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I use Laravel Horizon. And I really didn't understand from the documentation.

Should I not use the `config/queue.php` now?

On a production server, can I delete the [supervisor settings](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#configuring-supervisor) for standart Laravel queue because I am now using the [Horizon supervisor settings](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/horizon#supervisor-configuration)?

Comment: Horizon is not to replace Laravel's queue. Horizon uses the Redis queue you configured.

Answer (score 1):

You still need `queue.php`. Horizon is still based on Queue. Horizon augments Laravel's queue with additional features [[1]](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/horizon). It comes with a dashboard and requires Redis as your queue driver.

In terms of configuring of your supervisor, yes, it is a replacement. `queue:work` and `horizon:work` basically does the same thing. So you should delete `queue:work` supervisor configuration and continue using Horizon supervisor.

Some references you might be interested in:

- [What is the difference between artisan queue:work and artisan horizon:work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48789024/what-is-the-difference-between-artisan-queuework-and-artisan-horizonwork)
- [Relationship between Laravel Horizon and queue:work](https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/mrpoi5/relationship_between_laravel_horizon_and_queuework/)
- [Do I need run `queue:work` when I'm using horizon?](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/do-i-have-to-run-queuework-when-im-using-horizon)